# I need to generate Wordpress page ID in this script code

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need to get page ID by this code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
'PageType': 'ProductPage',
'email': '',
'ProductID': 'ProductID'
});
</script>
```

What variable code I need to replace 'ProductID' to get Wordpress page ID?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try with `get_the_ID()`

Comment: If I put in this script code, it does not work:

<script type="text/javascript">
dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
'PageType': 'ProductPage',
'email': '',
'ProductID': 'get_the_ID()'
});
</script>

Comment: Well I mean, `<?php the_ID(); ?>` if you could run PHP code there in the script..